# bson-objectid and mongo's auto generated objectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-objectid to generate ids to insert data into mongodb.

I worried that it will have clashed with mongo's auto generated objectID, is that possible? I know it's quite impossible to have redundancy using mongo's objectID even across document, but I'm not sure about bson-objectid in this case.

Answer (score 0):

mongos objectid is a variant of uuid constructed of:

```
a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

if the bson-objectid executable is run on a different machine (than mongod) then it would seem very unlikely to share the "machine identifier" plus the "process id". the machine identifier is possibly the MAC address as used in a type 1 uuid.

if the two run on the same machine, its plausible that bson-objectid uses the same "machine identifier" but then unlikely the "process id" or pid is the same. unlessssss its use the pid of mongod?! then a clash is possible.

of course one can leave it empty and it will generate one for you.

i cannot speak accurately to the guts of this bson-objectid library since it requires stepping through. but bearing in mind that node is not multi-threaded but multi-processed so you *should* get a different 2-byte process id per process.

but generally if its using a unique process id per spawned process then your code will break after 16M requests / second per process. no problem. however, if its using the parent process id for each spawned process then you will get into trouble.

so i would see what happens with a multi process system.

Comment: run on same machine like how? Imagine I'm doing a system that involve users, how much is the risk the app will break?

Comment: run on the same machine??? the mongo deamon and your node application that is using this bson-objectid. is your concern whether your app will clash with a mongo generated id created by some other process. or whether your own app using bson-objectid will clash with itself?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the documentation of https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-objectid

> The goal is to be 100% compatable with all bson's public API
>   implementation (found here:
>   https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js).

The given specs implements pretty much the same as mongo's ObjectId so

it is safe to use.